# SQL- Ignoring null value and not printing in order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to print each transition status to a new row , but the SQL query ignoring the null value

below is my actual table. old corresponds to old status and new corresponds to new status .timestamp is the only unique key of the table.

```
 id    name old new timestamp
12342   sas NULL Ld 8/28/18 9:01:45
12342   sas Ld  Ld  8/28/18 9:01:50
12342   sas Ld  Ld  8/28/18 9:01:51
12342   sas Ld  Ld  8/28/18 9:02:12
12342   sas Ld  Rd  8/28/18 9:09:45
12342   sas Rd  Rd  9/1/18 16:19:56
12342   sas Rd  Rd  9/6/18 13:58:37
12342   sas Rd  rsf 9/6/18 13:58:39
12342   sas rsf rsf 9/6/18 13:59:25
12342   sas NULL Ld 12/21/18 4:41:34
12342   sas Ld  Ld  12/21/18 4:41:43
12342   sas Ld  Ld  12/21/18 4:41:49
12342   sas Ld  PUB 12/21/18 4:41:56
```

I eliminating the redundant rows and printing only the row that had a change of status( NULL to LD, LD to Rd and so on)

once I eliminate the row, the table should look like below

```
id  name old    new timestamp
12342   sas NULL    Ld  1/1/19 1:45:45
12342   sas Ld      Rd  1/1/19 1:55:34
12342   sas Rd      RSF 1/3/19 15:52:21
12342   sas NULL    Ld  1/4/19 1:10:23
12342   sas Ld      Rd  1/7/19 12:05:54
12342   sas Rd      LP  1/7/19 12:23:45
12342   sas LP      Pub 1/14/19 14:23:25
```

I'm using  the below query to filter, but it's not giving me the required output

```
select id, name, old, new, date
from tablex
where Id in ( 12342)
and  old != new
order by  date asc
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Your sample data will never produce your desired results because for a start there is no "pub" in your sample data.

Comment: != returns null when either side is null (like other operators) & WHERE removes rows when the condition is non-true so your where clause is removing rows with null. When you make a [mre] that really is minimal you will get a faq. PS Please use standard spelling & punctuation.. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't work with your description. You say "timestamp is the only unique key of the table" but there are duplicates in your sample data. And the desired output values don't exist in your sample data. Help us to help you by providing an explanation and sample data that actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are getting burned by the TRI level nature of boolean expressions in most SQL implementations.  Instead of only returning TRUE or FALSE there is a third possible result. When one or more of the values being compared is NULL (aka missing) then the result is NULL rather than either TRUE or FALSE.

So you will have to explicitly account for the NULL values in your query. Something like:

```
and not ( (review_status_old=review_status_new)
       or (review_status_old is null and review_status_new is null)
        )
```